# How to get the Unicode of a character in android

Tags: android, unicode

I want to get the Unicode of character then i want to match with a Unicode ِ0650. Basically I want to find a specific Unicode from a string if it is found then i will remove that Character from the String.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this for it:

```
char character ='c';
int UniCode = ch;
System.out.println(code);
```

And Yes

just for escape char \ you have to use like char character = '\\';

Answer (score 1):

Try this line, it will return unicode of your `character`

```
 String.valueOf(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(character, 16)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just cast a char to an int. Like this:

```
char characterToCheck = '%';

int unicode = (int) characterToCheck;
```

So you could simply convert your String to a CharArray and loop trough it checking if the int equals 0650

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution,You can do it for any Java char using the one liner here:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString('÷' | 0x10000).substring(1) );
```

But it's only going to work for the Unicode characters up to Unicode 3.0, which is why I precised you could do it for any Java char.

Because Java was designed way before Unicode 3.1 came and hence Java's char primitive is inadequate to represent Unicode 3.1 and up: there's not a "one Unicode character to one Java char" mapping anymore (instead a monstrous hack is used).

So you really have to check your requirements here: do you need to support Java char or any possible Unicode character?